# Actionscript Date Comparison

Tags: actionscript, date, operators, equality

In my Actionscript code I have two dates:

```
var date1:Date = new Date(2011,1,1);
var date2:Date = new Date(2011,1,1);
```

This doesn't work:

```
var equal:Boolean = date1 == date2;
```

From reading I've found that this is a working alternative since it just gets the number of milliseconds from a standard point in time.

```
var equal:Boolean = date1.getTime() == date2.getTime();
```

So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't the normal equality operator work on Dates in actionscript?
2. ">" as well as "<" operators seem to work fine, but can they be trusted?
3. Why would they work but not the equality operator?
4. Is there a standard method I can use when comparing dates that just returns a -1, 0, or 1 (I realize I can easily create my own, but I would rather use an existing utility class)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Because Dates are objects (instances of a class), instead of a native data type, so they'll always be different unless it's different references to the same instance.
2. Probably, because they get transformed to a native format (number) when compared (see [type conversions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87)). Not sure if it's being cast to a number or a string though? Be sure to test
3. Because they're not equal; they're not the same object.
4. The comparison you made (using getTime()) is the best thing you can use I guess.

Answer (score 15):

Re: #4

You can use the ObjectUtil.dateCompare() function to get the results you are looking for.

[mx.utils.ObjectUtil.dateCompare()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#dateCompare%28%29)

Comment: Thanks! Will mark this as the answer if nobody else chimes in with the answer to the rest of the questions.